Triple integral problem whit ellipsoidal coordinates
I have to solve this integral
$$
\iiint_D e^{\frac{x + y}{\sqrt{2}}} \, dx \, dy \, dz,
$$
where $ D $ is the ellipsoid defined by: $ \frac{x^2 + y^2}{a^2} + \frac{z^2}{b^2} \leq 1 $.
I started with the ellipsoidal coordinates.
$$
x = a \rho \cos \theta \sin \phi, \
y = a \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi, \
z = b \rho \cos \phi,
$$
where $0 \leq \rho \leq 1, \ 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi , \  0 \leq \phi \leq \pi $.
The Jacobian determinant for this transformation is: $\left| J \right| = a^2b \rho^2 \sin \phi $.
So, the integral transforms as follows:
$$
\iiint_D e^{\frac{x + y}{\sqrt{2}}} \, dx \, dy \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^1 e^{\frac{a \rho (\cos \theta + \sin \theta) \sin \phi}{\sqrt{2}}} \cdot a^2b \rho^2 \sin \phi \, d\rho \, d\phi \, d\theta.
$$
Now I'm stuck and I can't go on, I tried with a couple of substitutions that didn't lead me to anything. I tried separating the variables but I think that the sine can help me integrate. Maybe I shouldn't use this change of coordinates? Am I missing any formula that can help me? Any help or suggestion is welcome, thank you all

something like Weierstrauss substitution would be nice for $\theta$ but I don't think it works on this domain

$$\begin{aligned}
I&=a^2b\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 e^{\frac{a\rho}{\sqrt 2}\sin\phi\cos\theta}e^{\frac{a\rho}{\sqrt 2}\sin\phi\sin\theta}\rho^2\sin\phi\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\phi\\
&=2\pi a^2b\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 \mathrm I_0(a\rho\sin\phi)\rho^2\sin\phi\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\phi\\
&=4\pi ab\int_0 ^1\rho\sinh(a\rho)\,\mathrm d\rho\\
&=4\pi ab\,\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}\int_0^1\cosh(a\rho)\,\mathrm d\rho\\
&=4\pi ab\,\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}\dfrac{\sinh(a)}{a}\\
&=4\pi b\dfrac{a\cosh(a)-\sinh(a)}{a}
\end{aligned}$$
where $\mathrm I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.
